# Simple HTML directory/index.html issue

Tags: html, hyperlink

I feel like a baby for having to do this but bear with me.  I'm trying to set up webpage structures on my desktop in a folder.  It's got an index.html and a couple folders of its own.  One folder, "research", has its own index.html.  I'm trying to link to this page from the higher index.html with  but instead of taking me to research/index.html it takes me to a 'file-directory view' (for lack of knowing what to call it) of the directory research/

Clearly I could fix this by doing  but that's annoying.  Thoughts?

Comment: By the way, the 'file-directory view' is called Directory Listing =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to browse locally, you will have to include the file name. in other words:

```
<a href='research/index.html'>research</a>
```

The reason it works on remote servers is because replacement is done by the web server so if you want research/ to work then you will need a local web server such as wamp on windows or mamp on mac.